# Last column not always displayed in html table inside bootstrap collapsed element when using chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to wrap an html table inside a div collapsing element using bootstrap but I get a weird behaviour on last column which is not always displayed on Chrome (44.0.2403.107 m), depending on window width. It's working fine on Firefox.

You can try the following fiddle --> https://jsfiddle.net/mattbt/5k7ym9qp/

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
         <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
      Collapsible Group Item #1
    </a>
  </h4>

    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="background-color: white;">
            <thead>
                <tr class="info">
                    <th>header</th>
                    <th style="width:30px;">header</th>
                    <th>header</th>
                    <th style="width:75px;">header header</th>
                    <th>header header</th>
                    <th>header header</th>
                    <th>last col</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbody-1">
                <tr id="rowscen-1">
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ut imperdiet nibh. Ut finibus lectus sed metus elementum aliquam. Etiam rhoncus varius malesuada. Integer id lorem ultrices, eleifend ex ut, dignissim lorem. Nunc commodo tincidunt euismod. Cras at dui libero. Sed viverra neque in risus maximus facilisis. Phasellus nulla nisi, pretium vitae vulputate at, ornare in arcu. Praesent mi nulla, tincidunt sed lacinia eget, molestie ut elit. Aliquam nec tristique est.</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ut imperdiet nibh. Ut finibus lectus sed metus elementum aliquam. Etiam rhoncus varius malesuada.</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ut imperdiet nibh. Ut finibus lectus sed metus elementum aliquam. Etiam rhoncus varius malesuada.</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ut imperdiet nibh. Ut finibus lectus sed metus elementum aliquam. Etiam rhoncus varius malesuada.</td>
                    <td class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ut imperdiet nibh. Ut finibus lectus sed metus elementum aliquam. Etiam rhoncus varius malesuada.</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
                    <td>Last Column text</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try and resize your browser window to see last column appear and disappear.

I guess it's just trivial but I'm stuck.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: this is because of your bootstrap collapsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using Bootstrap. You've got all it's predefined classes doing things such as collapsing like 'messerbill' pointed out in the comment below your question. I think when following examples from the internet you need to be careful about how much of the code you copy over as you may find parts of it are irrelevant to what you're looking for. Such as `panel-collapse` class in your code above.

Have a look at this fiddle and look at how the table is laid out using only bootstrap classes and no inline styling. I know it's not 100% the answer you were looking for. But I think it should at least point you in the right direction!

http://jsfiddle.net/w6u20yc9/

Comment: Thank you, adding `class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"` to th elements solved it. I though lost the chance to let the columns resize according to content which I don't know in advance. 
I know I should avoid inline styles :)